# Accessing ActiveX textbox value from cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I cannot post my code because it is company property, but the issue is that I would like to enter a cell formula so that it automatically updates when particular other cells change.

I have two columns, one for prices in USD and another for another currency. The other currency column is a simple "=SUM..." but the currency conversion to USD is always changing, and the prices are large enough that these changes matter. As such, I have the user enter the conversion value in the activex textbox, and I want to set the formula of the USD cells to be the price in USD, so obviously I need to get this conversion value, but I cannot just type in the textbox name, that does not work.

I am using VBA, but I would like to enter this directly into the cell as "=FORMULA", where formula contains the activeX textbox value, so that it automatically updates.

As far as I have found in VBA, if I want to assign a formula to a cell, I have to do so within a sub or function, so I have to call the sub every time I want to update the cells, but I want this to be as automatic as Excel is for other cell formulas.

I have been playing with Worksheet_Change and considered worksheet_open but have had other issues. For example, there are many different cells that could change that I have to monitor for change, and I cannot simply monitor the price column in the other currency for change because when cells update from a formula, Worksheet change does not show those cells as having changed.

Maybe this is as simple as setting the cell formulas on worksheet_open, but I also have not had luck with getting cell.formula to even work. I could discard the textbox for a regular cell which would totally solve this problem, but I also have a textbox_lostfocus sub that I need to run, and I don't know how to do that for a cell.

Sorry for the long post, in summary, how can I assess a textbox value for use in a cell formula ideally without using vba?

Comment: Please take the time to create and include a [mcve]. It doesn't have to be your company's super-secret code, only a reproducable scenario that illustrates the problem.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!*  That is a giant block of hard-to-read text.  Some formatting and spacing would be help make it easier for others to read (and therefore more likely to assist!)  In addition to the link above, be sure to check out the [tour] (and earn a badge!) as well as **"[ask]"**.  Here is a list of [tips from S.O.'s top user](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Fair enough, I will edit the post.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post bear with me

Comment: someone serious. It can be marked as complete by accepting an answer. Ill write a short one. Please don't write solved or anything similar in your post, we are not a forum but a Q&A site.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark on the left hand side of that answer btw.

Comment: @someoneserious no problem, there's a definite learning curve around here, and it can be a little intimidating when several veterans users are yelling at you to fix your stuff (I remember it well!)   ...Also, [here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to how to use markdown formatting in posts/comments.

Comment: While we're all learning, @Luuklag if mention `@` a user then it will fill in the name for you after a couple letters, plus it ensure that the user is notified of the message. :-)  (More on that: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).)

Comment: I know @ashleedawg, however this doesn't go for OP, they get notified automatically and I often see the name stripped from my comment in its entirety when using an @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what linked cells are for. You link your ActiveX textbox to a cell. The cell value then gets updated once you update the value of your textbox. You can reference this cell in your normal excel formulas. See here for a tutorial: https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/activex-controls/textbox/